# Show that $ \int_{k}^{2} \frac{1}{f(y)} =1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the problem:

> \begin{array}{l}{\text { A particular solution of the differential equation }} \\ {x \frac{\mathrm{d} v}{\mathrm{d} x}=f(v) \text { has } v=2 \text { when } x=\mathrm{e} \text { . }} \\ {\text { If } k \text { is the value of } v \text { when } x=1, \text { show that } \int_{k}^{2} \frac{1}{f(y)} \mathrm{d} y=1}\end{array}

I realize that:
$\int\frac{dv}{f(v)} = \int \frac{dx}{x}$. I am unsure of how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $y$ is just a bit confusing. Just replace it by $v$. Then, you have

$$\int_{v(1)}^{v(e)}\frac{dv}{f(v)} = \int_1^e\frac{dx}{x} = \ln e - \ln 1 = 1$$