# Show that $\int_{k}^{2} \frac{1}{f(y)} dy = 1$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let us have the differential equation $x\frac{dv}{dx}=f(v(x))$ and the solution $v$ s.t. $v(e)=2$. Let $v(1)=k$. Show that $$\int_{k}^{2} \frac{dy}{f(y)} = 1.$$

Can anyone please help me understand how to show that?

I was taught that $v$ is defined as $\frac yx$. I understand how to show that but how is it done if we assume that $v=\frac yx$?

Comment: Try to do some manipulation to this equation!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $ \int_{k}^{2} \frac{1}{f(y)} =1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3397716/show-that-int-k2-frac1fy-1)

Comment: @LadaDudnikova not really.

Comment: @Mathrix in this case you may link your question to the one provided, and explain what you don't understand particularly, additionally to that you do in the comments below, because the question is the same and it is a dublicate in the form presented now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rearrange and get
$$\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dv}{f(v)} \implies \int_1^e\frac{dx}{x} = \int_k^2\frac{dv}{f(v)}  \implies\ln(e) - \ln(1) = \int^2_k\frac{dv}{f(v)}$$

Let $v=y$

$$\implies 1-0 = 1 =\int^2_k\frac{dy}{f(y)}$$

Comment: I did the same thing without limits but I am stuck.

Comment: How did you do $f(v)=v$?

Comment: @Mathrix Oops! It was a typo. Fixed!

Comment: So we have actually nothing to do with $y$? I was taught $v$ stands for $\frac {y}{x}$.

Comment: Yeah, it's just a change in variable. For definite integral,we have $$\int^b_ag(y)dy = \int^b_ag(z)dz$$

Comment: Thanks! Do we end up like this as well if we assume $v=\frac yx$? Could you please show it, too?

Answer (score 3):

Substitute directly for $f$.  Use the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) to rewrite the reciprocal of the derivative outside of the fraction.  Use the chain rule (in reverse of the way you used it repeatedly for implicit differentiation) to simplify the product of derivative and the differential element.  Then use the data about the differential equation's particular values to change the endpoints of integration.  Now you have an elementary integral; evaluate it.

> \begin{align*}  \int_{k}^{2}\; \frac{1}{f(y)} \,\mathrm{d}y  &= \int_{k}^{2}\; \frac{1}{x \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}} \,\mathrm{d}y  \\      &= \int_{k}^{2}\; \frac{1}{x} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} \,\mathrm{d}y  \\      &= \int_{y = k}^{y = 2}\; \frac{1}{x}  \,\mathrm{d}x  \\      &= \int_{1}^{\mathrm{e}}\; \frac{1}{x}  \,\mathrm{d}x  \\    &= \left. \ln x \right|_1^{\mathrm{e}}  \\    &= 1-0  \text{.}  \end{align*}